# Laravel Eloquent hardcoded value in whereNotIn

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, subquery

In Laravel eloquent query using multiple columns for whereNotIn clause I need to hardcoded one of the DB::raw column for the value should be coming from a variable (loop variable). What is the best way to implement this?
This is my query and I need to change the hardcoded 1 in DB::raw('(1,user_profile.user_id')

```
$otherProfiles = Userprofile::where('user_id', '!=', $profile->user_id)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($userInterests) {
                foreach ($userInterests as $interest) {
                    $query->orWhere('interest', 'like', "%$interest%");
                };
            })
            ->whereNotIn(DB::raw('(1, user_profile.user_id)'), function ($query) {
                $query->select('sender_id', 'receiver_id')
                    ->from('email_reports');
            })
         
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->get();
```

Comment: can you show us the table structure and expected result you want?

Answer (score 0):

Manage to fix it by just simple concatenation
the code added were DB::raw('('. $profile->user_id . ', user_profile.user_id)')

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable as `$id` for your dynamic value:

```
$otherProfiles = Userprofile::where('user_id', '!=', $profile->user_id)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($userInterests) {
        foreach ($userInterests as $interest) {
            $query->orWhere('interest', 'like', "%$interest%");
        };
    })
    ->whereNotIn('user_id', $id), function ($query) {
        $query->select('sender_id', 'receiver_id')
            ->from('email_reports');
    })
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->get();
```